# Get the "alt" attribute from an image that resides inside an <a> tag

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

this should be fairly simple but for some reason, it doesn't work.

I want to get the "alt" attribute from an image that resides inside an  tag

```
<div id="album-artwork">
<ul>
   <li><a href="link to large image"><img src="thumbnail" alt="description of the image" /></a></li>
   ...
</ul>
</div>



$("#album-artwork a").click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();

var src = $(this).attr("href");
var alt = $(this).next("img").attr("alt");


alert(src); // ok!
alert(alt); //output: undefined

});
```

any ideas why next() doesn't work? Is there a better solution out there?

Thanks in advance
Marco

Comment: check my @user2727841 answer its tested and working!!!

Comment: Marco check my @user2727841 answer...

Answer (score 27):

It's because the image tag is inside the ul tag. next only looks for tags at the same level. You'll have to use

```
var alt = $(this).children("img").attr("alt");
```

EDIT: included the additional " that was missing

Comment: i've just answered my own question... forgot about siblings and childs... your answer helps confirm my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

```
$(this).find('img').attr('alt');
```

Answer (score 3):

Try `$(this).find('img')` instead to select some element *within* the link.

Answer (score 3):

or

```
$('img', this).attr('alt');
```

Test : **http://jsbin.com/amado4**

Comment: jQuery rewrites `$(child, parent)` internally to `$(parent).find(child)`.

Answer (score 2):

Nevermind. I just got it... I've realized that the `img` is not a sibling of `<a>` but a child of `<a>`

This is the correct syntax

```
var alt = $(this).children("img").attr("alt");
```

Answer (score 1):

Won't .next pick up the next element which is the next Li and not the IMG?

Answer (score 1):

try this tested and its working!!!

```
<div id="album-artwork">
<ul>
   <li><a href="javascript:void(0);"><img src="images/ajax-loader.gif" alt="ajax-loader" /></a></li>
   <li><a href="javascript:void(0);"><img src="images/close.png" alt="close" /></a></li>
   <li><a href="javascript:void(0);"><img src="images/copy.png" alt="copy" /></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

and jQuery code is

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#album-artwork a").click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            var src = $(this).attr("href");
            //var alt = $(this).next("img").attr("alt");
            var alt = $(this).children().attr("alt");
            //find function also do the same thing if you want to use.
            /*var alt = $(this).find("img").attr("alt");*/

            alert(src); // ok!
            console.log(src); // ok!
            alert(alt); //output: not undefined now its ok!
            console.log(alt); //output: not undefined now its ok!
        });
    });
```

the `children()` function find any children but if you want to find any specific children define the children name like this `children("img")` **OR** `children("button")`.

Answer (score 0):

Dont complicate:

```
$('img').on({'click': function(){
    var alt = this.alt;
```