# linking an image and text

Tags: html, hyperlink, caption

I'd like to wrap an html link tag around both and image and a caption, so something like

```
<a href="link"><img src="...">Caption Text</img></a>
```

The caption should go below the image, but I'm not sure of a good way to do that (adding a `<br>` works, but seems unclean). I'd like to be able to use a styled element, but I can't put a `div` inside of there.

Comment: `</img>`? Never seen that before. Are you sure that's valid HTML?

Comment: so you want the image above the caption, do you want to use CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap the caption inside a span

```
<a href="link"><img src="..."/><span style="display: block;">Caption Text</span></a>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZgKqF/

Comment: Describe wrap? not sure what your after here.

Comment: sorry, not wrap. it doesn't put it on a new line

Comment: Try now, adding display block will put the text on a new line

Comment: That's what I was looking for. I moved it to a CSS file since I will have multiple captions.

Answer (score 2):

Try this - [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/CWDk4/)

No need to change your **HTML**

```
<a href="link">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/100" />
    Caption Text
</a>
```

**CSS**

```
a {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    border: 2px solid orange;
}

img {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Seems like there are multiple wys to do this.

Comment: Yes :) Just try to avoid introducing unnecessary tags and elements to keep your markup as clean as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Try it this way : `<a href="link"><img src="..." alt="Caption Text" /></a>`

Then use javascript to display the alt attribute and display with javascript. Look at this for reference [Get the "alt" attribute from an image that resides inside an <a> tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3883882/get-the-alt-attribute-from-an-image-that-resides-inside-an-a-tag)

Answer (score -1):

You can make the `a` behave like a div (in regard to how it can be styled) with

```
display: block
```

Comment: In how it displays and handles padding and margin yes it does, the default value for display is "inline", so vertical padding and margin are ignored